# Interpolating 3D volumetric data with scipy's RegularGridInterpolator

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a 3D array with some volumetric data, i.e. at each grid points I have some value representing a magnitude of a certain quantity. I want to interpolate that array using scipy's `RegularGridInterpolator`, but I am using it wrong.

To have a simple example, I use here a circle which I would like to interpolate. The original circle looks quite rough, as you can see below.

[image: rough circle]

According to my understanding of the docs of `RegularGridInterpolator`, [link here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html), I thought I need to provide the new coordinates for the interpolation function as an array of the shape `[[x1, y1, z1],[x2, y2, z2],...]`. My idea was to promote my new coordinate vectors to column vectors and then combine them with `hstack`, but that is not working as my data returned from the interpolator has the wrong shape.

Here is my code:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp

def make_simple_3Dplot( data2plot, xVals, yVals, zVals, N_contLevels=8, fname_plot='' ):

    contLevels  = np.linspace( np.amin(data2plot), 
                               np.amax(data2plot),
                               N_contLevels)[1:].tolist()
    fig1    = mlab.figure( bgcolor=(1,1,1), fgcolor=(0,0,0),size=(800,600))

    XX, YY, ZZ = np.meshgrid(xVals, yVals, zVals, indexing='ij' )
    contPlot = mlab.contour3d( XX, YY, ZZ, 
                               data2plot, contours=contLevels,
                               transparent=True, opacity=.4,
                               figure=fig1
                             )
    mlab.xlabel('x')
    mlab.ylabel('y')
    mlab.zlabel('z')

    mlab.show()

# define original coordinates
x_min, y_min, z_min = 0, 0, 0
x_max, y_max, z_max = 10, 10, 10
Nx, Ny, Nz = 20, 30, 40
x_arr = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, Nx)
y_arr = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, Ny)
z_arr = np.linspace(z_min, z_max, Nz)

# center of circle
xc, yc, zc = 3, 5, 7

# radius of circle
rc = 2

# define original data
data_3D_original = np.zeros( (Nx, Ny, Nz) )
for ii in range(Nx):
    for jj in range(Ny):
        for kk in range(Nz):
            if np.sqrt((x_arr[ii]-xc)**2 + (y_arr[jj]-yc)**2 + (z_arr[kk]-zc)**2) < rc:
                data_3D_original[ii,jj,kk] = 1.

make_simple_3Dplot( data_3D_original, x_arr, y_arr, z_arr )

# spatial coordinates for interpolation
step_size = np.mean(np.diff(x_arr))/5.
x_interp = np.arange(x_arr[0], x_arr[-1], step_size ) 
y_interp = np.arange(y_arr[0], y_arr[-1], step_size )
z_interp = np.arange(z_arr[0], z_arr[-1], step_size )

# make interpolation function
func_interp = interp.RegularGridInterpolator( (x_arr, y_arr, z_arr), data_3D_original )

# make coordinates for interpolation, first transform vectors for coordinates
# into column vectors and then stack them together 
points = np.hstack( (x_interp[...,None], y_interp[...,None], z_interp[...,None]) )

data_3D_interp = func_interp(points)

print(data_3D_interp.shape, x_interp.shape, y_interp.shape, z_interp.shape)
```

The output, besides the plot, reads `(96,) (96,) (96,) (96,)` whereas it should be `(96,96,96) (96,) (96,) (96,)`. Clearly, I am missing something. Furthermore, this only works if all coordinate vectors are of same length, which they are not in my actual use case. So what am I doing wrong here?

The version of the relevant libraries I am using (I do not think this plays a role here though, but I also think it is good practice to include them):

```
numpy version: 1.20.3
scipy version: 1.7.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal snippet to perform interpolation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def model(x, y, z):
    return np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2)

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 102)

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing="ij")

F = model(X, Y, Z)

interpolator = interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), F)

points = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
])

interpolator(points)
# array([0.01414426, 1.00005101, 1.00004901, 1.00010003])
```

The memory issue is due to cubic complexity of the rectangular 3D grid.

```
F.nbytes / 2**20 # 7.8598 Mb
```

Increasing resolution by a factor 10, will consume 1000 times more memory, in this scenario it will consume approximately 8 Gb.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the cubic complexity, that will make it a really challenging interpolation then with my ~1000x500x500 grid....

Answer (score 0):

After being away from the problem for a short amount of time, I realized what the problem was while doing the laundry. As I want to have interpolation on the full 3D grid spanned by `x_interp`, `y_interp`, and `z_interp`, I need to provide a *full* list of coordinates using `numpy.meshgrid()`.

This is what I need to change in the code

```
XX, YY, ZZ = np.meshgrid( x_interp, y_interp, z_interp, indexing='ij' )
points = list( zip(XX.ravel(), YY.ravel(), ZZ.ravel() ) )
data_3D_interp = func_interp(points)
data_3D_interp = np.reshape(data_3D_interp, (len(x_interp), len(y_interp), len(z_interp)) )
```

Setting `step_size` to 1/10th of the original value, results in the following plot. I am somewhat disappointed by the result, but I guess this is what is possible here. Playing around with the interpolation methods might improve the result though, but that is something I cannot test on my computer, as I get a memory error:  `numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate ...`

[image: interpolated circle]